# Nhibernate mapping and versioned entities

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I am working on a project using NHibernate as its ORM.

The persistence model being used creates a new row for an entity (with a new entity.Id) for each successive save. All revisions of an entity are linked by an OriginatingId column, where the entity with the max(entity.Id) for a given OriginatingId is the current revision.

I have a situation where I have two entities A and B.

B needs to contain a reference to A. This can be done by mapping using a join on B.A_Id = A.Id.

The problem is when A is saved the most recent revision of A has a new Id, so if B remains unchanged it references a stale version of entity A.

Using the mapping properties of NHibernate how can I ensure that the A_Id property of entity B is updated when entity A is saved?

Comment: The versioning design you've decided to use, is in a nutshell introducing new objects (if their surrgated key ID is changed == not the same - these objects are different). ORM **as is** - is not designed for such scenario. It keeps references/relation ID to original objects. **That is the strongest part of ORM: that this promise is valid**. From my experinece, that kind of versioning is not suitable for ORM. You are not doing stuff supported by NHibernate design. Sorry for not having better comment...

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the versioning mechanism used does not fit well with NHibernate, but there's nothing I can do to change that now. If there is no way of handling this scenario I may have to manage this situation explicitly in my DAL. It's a bit of a mess!

Comment: Well, I am not sure, how you will do that. How yo will find that any object loaded into session, which **is not dirty** has a bad (old) reference id? and what about all the object not loaded into session. I am just trying to say: You will fail, or pay so much energy... that... Sorry for not having nice words... but I did suffered enough to at least try discourage you from "changing reference model" becuase of versioning. Good luck with mighty NHibernate anyway...

Answer (score 0):

When using this versioning there is always a master entry for each Entity and a versioned part. You have to work with the historic data sooner than you think so you need to access it. References are no problem now because the master Id does not change. The Id of the changing part could also be a changed date.

```
class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string NaturalKey { get; protected set; } // never changes
    public virtual Ilist<BData> Data { get; protected set; }

    private BData _changedData;
    public virtual BData ActualData { get { return _changedData == null ? _changedData = Data.Last().Clone() : _changedData; } }
}

class BData
{
    public BData Clone() { ... }
}

mapping.List(x => x.Data, p => p.OrderBy("changedDate"))
```